# Is this epsilon-delta proof that limit is not a number correct?

Tags: limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I'd like to proof the following statement wrong by using the epsilon-delta definition:

\begin{equation}
 \lim_{x\to 2}(x-2) = 1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \lim_{x\to 2}(x-2) = 1 \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0 ~ \exists \delta > 0  ~:~ 0 < |x-2| < \delta \implies |x-2 -1|<\varepsilon
\end{equation}

I apply the triangle inequality

\begin{equation}
 |x-2| =  |x-2+1-1| = |x-3+1| \leq |x-3| + 1 < \varepsilon+ 1
\end{equation}

And I reach

\begin{equation}
 |x-2|  < \varepsilon+ 1
\end{equation}

Am I in the right way?

---

**EDIT**

I tried a different approach, could you check if it is now correct??

I'm assuming that the following statement is true and try to reach a contradiction.

\begin{equation}
 \lim_{x\to 2}(x-2) = 1 \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0 ~ \exists \delta > 0  ~:~ 0 < |x-2| < \delta \implies |x-2 -1|<\varepsilon
\end{equation}

I assume $0 < |x-2| < \delta $. Let  $\varepsilon = 0.5$. Then by assumption it is true:

$|x-2-1| <\varepsilon= 0.5 $

However, I can't find any $\delta$ such that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ implies $|x-2-1| < 0.5$. This is because if $x$ lies in $(2-\delta,2+\delta)$, then this would have to impliy that $x$ lies in $(2.5,3.5)$ which is not true.

Now I'm asking, is my reasoning correct? If not why not?

(BTW  I had already tried other ways to prove this, just wanted to try a different approach)

Comment: Intuitively I understand that the result shows the distance form x to 2 cant be less than 1 but not really sure about it

Comment: What is the negation of the definition of limit in this context?  So the definition of limit going to $1$ here would be that *for every* $\epsilon > 0$ we can always find a $\delta >0$ such that....  yada yada.  The negation of this begins "*There exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ we have...*"  Begin by picking such an $\epsilon$ and proving that regardless which $\delta$ you take you always have...

Comment: No, it (happily) does not prove that "$x$ cant be less than $1$". And you are not "in the right way". However, you correctly wrote the formal definition of $\lim_{x\to 2}(x-2)=1.$ Now write down its negation (following JMoravitz's hint) and try to prove it. Alternatively, prove that $\lim_{x\to 2}(x-2)=0$ and use the uniqueness of limit in a Hausdorff space like $\Bbb R.$

Comment: Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and consider what happens when $\frac{7}{4}\lt x\lt\frac{9}{4}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that a limit is incorrect using epsilon delta definition of a limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704656/how-to-prove-that-a-limit-is-incorrect-using-epsilon-delta-definition-of-a-limit)

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments guys, they have been very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

To show the limit is not equal to $1$, it suffices to prove the negation... that is, that there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ we can always find some $x$ with $|x-2|<\delta$ such that $|(x-2)-1|>\epsilon$

Let us take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$

Then, whatever $\delta$ happened to be, let us take $x = \min(2.1,2+\frac{\delta}{2})$.  We use this minimum here as a just in case $2.1$ fell outside the range.

Then it is clear that $|x-2|<\delta$ as well as that $|(x-2)-1|\geq 0.9>0.5=\epsilon$

Answer (score -2):

Suppose I hypothesize
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$$
To show this is false, I want to prove the negation of it's definition.
The definition is: $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x: \;(0 < |x - a| < \delta) \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, so it's negation would be $\exists \epsilon > 0\forall\delta>0\exists x:( 0 < |x - a| < \delta) \land|f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon$

For your example, choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Now for any $\delta > 0$, we know that $|x-2| < \delta \implies -|x-2| > -\delta$.

Choose $x=2+\min(\frac{\delta}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ so that $|x-2|< \delta$. At this $x$, if $\delta \geq 1$, we have:
$$|x-3| = \frac{1}{2}\geq\epsilon$$
If instead $\delta < 1$, then $-\frac{\delta}{2}>-\frac{1}{2}$ we have
$$|x-3| = \left|\frac{\delta}{2}-1\right| \geq 1 - \frac{\delta}{2} > 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} = \epsilon$$
And so we've proven the negation i.e $$\exists \epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\forall \delta>0 \exists x=2+\min\left(\frac{\delta}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right): |x-2|<\delta \land |x-2-1| \geq \epsilon \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: Your negation is incorrect.  In particular how you are handling $x$'s and the $\implies$ sign.

Comment: @JMoravitz I tried editing it. Could you tell me if it's okay now?

Comment: You have not correctly demonstrated the existence of an $x$ satisfying what you want.  In particular, with $x=3$ your inequalities are false.  $|3-2-1|$ is not greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Sam No it is not. In particular (even if you assume $|x-2|<\delta$, which you should write explicitely), $ 1- |x-2|>1+\delta$ is wrong.

Comment: Ahh yeah I found the issue. it should've been $1 - \delta$.